# RegEx Match string between angle brackets and ignore newline

Tags: regex, string

I think I've nearly got this figured out but I cant for life of me figure out why its removing the first part of "little rock"

Heres the string I'm working with:

`"<Telerik.Sitefinity.GeoLocations.Model.Address>\n  <City>Little Rock</City>`

Here's my RegEX:

`/(?<=>[^\\n]).+?(?=\<)/gm`

And here's my results so far:

`ittle Rock`

I'm trying to capture the text between the angled brackets but also ignore any \n values.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it an actual newline, or literally `\n` ? The `.+?` Does not match a newline. One way to write it: `(?<=>)(?:(?!\\n)[^\r\n<>])*(?=<)` https://regex101.com/r/qhqdvz/1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2770274 - it's about parsing XHTML, but the answer is the same - use XML parser, not regexes

Comment: @Thefourthbird its literally a \n in string form. And that worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: `(?<=>(?!\\n))[^<>]*(?=<)` [works, too](https://regex101.com/r/dpskJd/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looking at the OP's pattern, I think that would be a better pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=>(?!\\n))[^<>]*(?=<)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dpskJd/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=>(?!\\n))` - a positive lookbehind that requires (immediately to the left of the current location) a `>` char not immediately followed with `\n` two-char sequence to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^<>]*` - zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `(?=<)` - a positive lookahead that requires `<` char at the right of the current location.

**Variations**

```
(?<=>(?!\\n)).*?(?=<)
(?<=>(?!\\n))[^<>]*
```